# Custom pipeline component ssis c# how to display errors from validate function

Tags: c#, ssis, pipeline

I created a custom data flow transformation component with a user interface using c #. I have created two class one that inherits from the PipelineComponent class which I modified my validation function.
and one that inherits from the IDtsComponentUI class to create a form.
I would like to display error messages from the validate function in my user interface.
Can someone help me please?

```
public override DTSValidationStatus Validate()
    {
        DTSValidationStatus validationStatus;

        if ((ComponentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager == null ? 0 : 1) == 0)
        {
            bool bCancel;
           ComponentMetaData.FireError(-1071636454, ComponentMetaData.Name, "the connection manager is required","",0,out bCancel);

            validationStatus = DTSValidationStatus.VS_ISBROKEN;
        }

        else validationStatus= DTSValidationStatus.VS_ISVALID;
        return validationStatus;

   }
```

here is an example of my user interface

```
   public OptionSetForm(IDTSComponentMetaData100 metaData, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.metaData = metaData;

        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        //    ConfigureControlsFromConnectionManager();
        this.connectionService = (IDtsConnectionService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IDtsConnectionService));
        this.designTimeInstance = metaData.Instantiate();
        //  this.designTimeInstance.ProvideComponentProperties();
        this.errorCollector = this.serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IErrorCollectionService)) as IErrorCollectionService;
        this._designerHost = this.serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;

        userControlGeneralConfigurationsOptionSet = new UserControlGeneralConfigurationsOptionSet(this.connectionService, this.metaData,this.designTimeInstance);



         userControlMappingOptionSet = new UserControlMappingOptionSet(this.connectionService, this.metaData, this.designTimeInstance,this.userControlGeneralConfigurationsOptionSet);




        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please be careful tagging your questions.  The language C uses the tag [tag:c] and the language C# uses the tag [tag:c#].  The two languages are quite different — mistagging could get you downvote, though with luck it was fixed quick enough that it won't be a major problem.  (You might still get downvotes — I'm not a C# programmer and can't tell you whether they're justified.)